# Importing shapefile from ArcGIS to SQL Server database without using deprecated geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql-server, error-000210

I am having issues with importing the shapefile in ArcGIS Pro into the SQL Server database. It shows an error output and an empty table when it is imported.

The only time I see this is working is when using importing it to a geodatabase, which appears to be deprecated.

I am using ArcGIS Pro version 2.9.8 to import a shapefile to SQL Server database version 15.0.18424.0.

I've tried importing the shapefile as a feature class to the database, and get:

> error 000210: Cannot create output. Failed to execute
> (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).

I get this error from the database type SQL Server.

However, I am able to see the imported shapefile from database type Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server. I can also see more information on what schema is used with the database type Enterprise Geodatabase in SQL Server, but not with database type SQL Server.

Has anyone had this problem before, or knows what the actual issue might be to be able to fix this problem?

Comment: If the duplicate does not help then please include more details about the parameter values you are using with the Feature Class To Feature Class tool.